# convert ambiguous reference to swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3

I am trying to convert to Swift 3 and receive the following error:

> '?' must be followed by a call, member lookup, or subscript

My code:

```
var superview = containerView.superview

if type(of: superview?) === UIWindow.self { //I GET AN ERROR HERE
    superview = containerView
}
```

Suggestions?

Comment: if let superview = containerView.superview {
    let v = superview.isKind(of: UIWindow.self)
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest and most natural way to test type is the `is` keyword:

```
var superview = containerView.superview

if superview is UIWindow {
    superview = containerView
}
```